# Green arrow notifications Google Play Store developer console

Tags: google-play-store

I'm not quite sure when have these arrows
[image: thse arrows]
appeared as some sort of notifications but I'm also not sure what they mean.

What do they notify about?

Comment: What arrows? (Assume people can't follow your link.) And, if this is really about the Google Developer Console, while I suppose technically a Web app, this is probably a better question for [so].

Comment: Yes it is about the Google Developer Console, and while checking for many similar questions on StackOverflow one of the few that had a comment on which they said that questions about the Google Developer Console are better suited here.

Anyway I updated the uploaded picture(uploaded it to the site directly, no web link) has to work now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following notification appears when unpublished changes are ready to be tested.

Source: Open the developer console ->Game services ->Choose your app->Publishing. There you will find what the notification arrows mean. Note that you can't see the explanation for the arrows there, unless you have changes to be tested. I hope this is enough of a source!

Cheers!

Comment: Unless you downvote from pure professionalism, you could at least add a comment and say what's wrong.

Comment: Your explanation is a little light. Can you expand on it? Link to a source?

Comment: Light? I don't see any reason why the explanation should be any more complicated than it is for such a simple question. As for the source, I hope that it's better now. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I was simply pointing out a possible reason for the downvote.